# Is there a EURO or CNY fiat currency cryptocurrency peg like USDT (USD tether)?

Tags: currencies, fiat

Tether is based out of Singapore if I'm correct and they currently have a USD cryptocurrency peg called USDT. But is there a EURO or CNY currency peg like USDT?